# Can I use parameter insertion to specify column names for MySQL queries?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I want to know if it is possible to use parameter insertion for column names into MySQL queries using Python.

Consider the following two queries, both of which are passed to `MySQLCursor.execute()`. The first:

```
query = (
      'SELECT username, COUNT(*)'
      'FROM `entry`'
      'GROUP BY username;'
)
cursor.execute(query)
```

And the second:

```
query = (
      'SELECT %s, COUNT(*)'
      'FROM `entry`'
      'GROUP BY %s;'
)
data = ('username', 'username')
cursor.execute(query, data)
```

The first of these returns the results I expect (a count of each how many times a distinct value appears in the username column) and the second returns unexpected results, specifically `[(u'username', n)]` where `n` is the total number of rows in the database.

The problem in the second query is that the parameters are interpreted as a string by the query. Is there a way to insert them such that they can be interpreted as a non-string? I want to do this in a way that is safe from Injection attacks.

Answer (score -1):

It is not recommended to use the 2nd syntax, the 1st one is ok and safe.

Comment: Why is it not recommended? I understand the first one is safe but it doesn't not allow me to dynamically pass in column names for selection.

Comment: why you wanna dynamically pass column ? because you know the column of evry table you should just create function that specific every column name.

Comment: It would be better reuse of code to be able to pass column names dynamically as I want to perform the same query on multiple columns and display the results in the same way.

Comment: you should explain why it is not recommended, also every code example in the web uses the second syntax